# Errors in discounts in a simple java program

Tags: java

So, in my program, it runs and displays correctly, but my discounts do not calculate correctly, hence errors.

Here is the question:

> Our Java Coffee Web business decided to give discounts to volume buyers. The discount is based on the following table:

```
Order Volume   Discount
>=25  bags     5% of total price
>=50  bags    10% of total price
>=100 bags    15% of total price
>=150 bags    20% of total price  
>=200 bags    25% of total price
>=300 bags    30% of total price
```

> Each bag of coffee costs £1.75. Write an application that accepts the number of bags ordered and prints out the total cost of the order in the following style:

```
Number of Bags Ordered=  173 - £302.75
Discount:    20% - £60.55   
Your total charge is:   £242.20
£242.20
```

My program runs, but gives the following for the same input:

```
Please enter your required number of Bags :173
Number of Bags Ordered: 302.75
Discount:0.25

Your total charge is:302.50
```

Code is as shown:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.00");

System.out.print("Please enter your required number of Bags :");
numberOfBags = scanner.nextInt();

{
    if ( numberOfBags > 299) {
        discount = 0.30;  
    }
    else if (numberOfBags < 199) {
        discount = 0.25;
    }
    else if ( numberOfBags < 149) {
        discount = 0.20;
    }
    else if ( numberOfBags < 99) {
        discount = 0.15;
    }
    else if ( numberOfBags < 49) {
        discount = 0.10;
    }
    else if ( numberOfBags < 24) {
        discount = 0.05;
    }
    if (numberOfBags<=24)
    {
        discount = .00;
    }

    totalDiscount =numberOfBags * pricePerBag *discount;

    totalCost = numberOfBags * pricePerBag;
    finalTotal =totalCost - discount;

    System.out.println("Number of Bags Ordered: " + numberOfBags *pricePerBag);
    System.out.println ("Discount:"      + discount );
    System.out.print("\r"+"Your total charge is:" +df.format(finalTotal));
}
```

Comment: You didnt even tell us what the problem was. "*Discounts don't calculate correctly.*" How should they calculate? How are they calculating now? Please reformat your question to include what *specifically* confuses you

Comment: Hi VinceI showed expected output

Answer (score 0):

Not a Java problem, but a logic one. You aren't printing the part you want to.

You are just printing the `discount` variable in:

```
System.out.println ("Discount:"      + discount );
```

It seems that you want to apply the discount percent to the total price (prior to discount). After all, it's the amount of discount as a percent. So print the correct variable: `totalDiscount`.

For the `finalTotal`, subtract `totalDiscount` from `totalCost`.

Answer (score 0):

```
totalDiscount =numberOfBags * pricePerBag *discount;
totalCost = numberOfBags * pricePerBag;
        finalTotal =totalCost - discount;
```

Unless it's a typo I believe you only need to change **discount** in the **totalCost** to **totalDiscount**.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys...the wife sorted me in the end..

I had my >=
 the wrong ways around..I had set <=

NOW..output is :

Please enter your required number of Bags :173
Number of Bags Ordered: 302.75
Discount:20.0% £60.55

Your total charge is:242.20